# How to convert hex data from a text file into string file

Tags: c#, hex

I have a list of data in a text file, which is written in hex like this:

```
AE 66 55 78 FF 6A 48 40 CA BC 1B 2C 18 94 28 28 
CF EA 02 00 02 51 23 05 0E F2 DD 5A E5 38 48 48 
CA BC 1B 2C 18 94 28 40 EE B6 65 87 E3 6A 48 48 
..
```

And I want to convert the values into char in another text file

I have tried this in c#:

```
 private static void OpenFile()
            {
ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();

                string str = string.Empty;
                using (System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader
                    (new System.IO.FileStream(
                        "hexa2.txt",
                        System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                        System.IO.FileAccess.Read,
                        System.IO.FileShare.None), Encoding.UTF8))
 using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("sms23.txt"))
                {
                   str = @"the path";
                    Byte[] bytes = ascii.GetBytes(str);
                    foreach (var value in bytes)
                        sw.WriteLine("{0:X2}", value);
                    sw.WriteLine();
                    String decoded = ascii.GetString(bytes);
                    sw.WriteLine("Decoded string: '{0}'", decoded);
                }
           }
```

I expect that every byte will be converted into char. e.g. "EE" is  "î"

Comment: So.. What is the problem you're encountering? An Exception? Strange results?

Comment: in the new text file, the values ​​remain in the hex format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a text file, not a binary file, so you must read the hex strings, convert then to the respective number and then get the corresponding char for that number.

```
// string input = @"EE B6 45 78 FF 6A 48 40 CA BC 1B 2C 18 94 28 28 
// CF EA 02 00 00 00 00 00 0E F2 DD 5A E4 38 48 48 
// CA BC 1B 2C 18 94 28 40 EE B6 45 78 FF 6A 48 48 ";
string input = File.ReadAllText("yourFile.txt");
string output = new string(
    input.Replace("\n"," ").Replace("\r","")
        .Split(new char[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(x=>(char)Convert.ToInt32(x,16))
        .ToArray()
);
File.WriteAllText("newFile.txt",output);
//Output: î¶ExÿjH@Ê¼←,↑?((Ïê☻     ♫òÝZä8HHÊ¼←,↑?(@î¶ExÿjHH
```

You don't specified an encoding, so I'm just casting the hex to char directly. To Specify the encoding you should use the bellow code

```
byte[] dataArray = 
    input.Replace("\n"," ").Replace("\r","")
        .Split(new char[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(x=>(byte)Convert.ToInt32(x,16))
        .ToArray();
string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataArray);
```

Where you can replace `Encoding.UTF8` for the desired one.

Comment: i have no idea, why the output is so strange !!
it should be coordinates

Comment: @HMZ either you are using the wrong encoding, or your data is wrong. I Updated my code with a way to specify which encoding you're using.

Comment: How does the output look like ?

Comment: @HMZ With UTF8 is `?Ex?jH@'←,↑?((??☻     ♫??Z?8HH'←,↑?(@?Ex?jHH`. None of the encodings I tried gave coordinates as result. Maybe your data is wrong. Where did you get the file?

Comment: @HMZ well, I don't know this file type, but maybe it doesn't give what you're expecting it to give. How do you know it gives coordinates as an hex string that represents chars?

Comment: @HMZ can you share the link you used to download the file?

Comment: @HMZ and how are you getting the data? Because every export option I tried, none gave me an HEX string.

Answer (score 0):

```
string hex = File.ReadAllText("file.txt").Replace(" ","").Replace(Environment.NewLine,"");
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
             .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
             .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
             .ToArray();


File.WriteAllBytes( "file.bin", result);
```

Comment: there is an OutOfRangeException here Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16)

it should be Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length-1)